# Is there an argument to force UTF8 in igraph functions?

Tags: r, function, utf-8, rstudio, igraph

I am trying to use an adjacency matrix that has labels in UTF-8. Is there a way to make sure iGraph functions use UTF8, something along the line of "encoding = "UTF8""? This is to avoid the following result (French text on a japanese system shows kanji instead of french diacritics). Thanks for any pointers.

```
> m1 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m, mode = "directed", weighted = TRUE)
> m1
```

> ```
> > IGRAPH 7a99453 DNW- 391 1454 -- 
> + attr: name (v/c), weight (e/n)
> + edges from 7a99453 (vertex names):
>  [1] Accept     ->Accepter    Acknowledge->Appr馗ier   Acknowledge->Confirmer   Acknowledge->Conscient  
>  [5] Acknowledge->Consid駻er  Acknowledge->Constater   Acknowledge->Convenir    Acknowledge->Donner   
> + ... omitted several edges
> ```

As per requested:

R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252    LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=French_France.1252

Actually, this may not be an issue with igraph, but with RStudio, since I just realised that although my tables are properly displayed with the View() command, if I just call them in the console, the French diacritics are displayed with Japanese kanji. In any cases, igraph also does this.

Comment: For completeness,  could you please type `sessionInfo()` and show us the `locale` part of the output?  I realize that you may be trying to run your system in Japanese, but display French text. That is fair enough,  but it would help to understand your environment.